# Thin client PXE boot

Tags: linux, ssh, boot, thin-client

Basically here is what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to boot a client remotely (using PXE boot). Over PXE boot I want to start a minimal linux distribution with X and ssh. Then I want to connect using ssh -Y to a remote server (on which I do not having root privileges), booting the window manager there. Eventually I'm planning to make the whole process automated.

My question is:

Is there a more refined way of doing this? Are there any recommendations for a light-weight linux distro that I can boot over PXE (preferably from a remote location for now, i.e not saved on my LAN server)?

I have heard of thinstation but their main-site appears to be down.

Comment: Although [thinstation.net](http://www.thinstation.net) seems down/broken you can still reach [thinstation.net/TSoM/](http://www.thinstation.net/TSoM/) and [sourceforge.net/thinstation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/thinstation/). So you can look around.